# How can I put code in MyFile.tab.cc?

Tags: bison

I am trying to follow the basic advice of the C++ example in 'info bison', so I have a `Driver` class and a Test.yy file:

```
%skeleton "lalr1.cc"

%{
class Driver;
#include "Expression.hpp"
#define YYSTYPE Expression
%}

%parse-param { Driver& driver }
%lex-param { Driver& driver }
%defines
%locations

%{
#include "Driver.H"
%}

%%
input: {};
```

When I bison that file, though, the `#include "Driver.H"` ends up in Test.tab.hh before the definition of `yy::parser`.  That's too soon, since I want to use `yy::parser::token_type` and so on from within Driver.H.

If my `#include` comes after a `%union` declaration, it ends up in Test.tab.cc as desired.  But what if I want to use a `YYSTYPE` instead of a `%union`?  What exactly determines whether a `%{` block ends up in the header or parser source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [bison manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Prologue-Alternatives.html), the positioning of a prologue (`%{` block) depends on whether it precedes or follows the `%union` declaration:

> This distinction in functionality between the two Prologue sections is established by the appearance of the %union between them. This behavior raises a few questions. First, why should the position of a %union affect definitions related to YYLTYPE and yytokentype? Second, what if there is no %union? In that case, the second kind of Prologue section is not available. This behavior is not intuitive.

Fortunately, you can use `%code` declarations to explicitly declare where you want code blocks to appear in generated code. Generally, you would use `%code requires` (which goes before `YYSTYPE` is declared) and `%code provides` (which goes afterwards). You can also use `%code top` for the case where you don't want the code to appear in the header at all. The precise semantics of the various `%code` sections are summarized [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/_0025code-Summary.html).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation that a `%union` makes the difference.  Unfortunately, I'm using Bison 2.3, which doesn't seem to have `%code`. Fortunately, if I both define `YYSTYPE` and put `%union { never_compiled }`, my `YYSTYPE` takes precedence.

Comment: @aschepler: ok. When using antediluvian tool versions, it is always helpful to mention the fact in the question. Of course, you could just upgrade.